# Superponer carrusel a barra de navegación en bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

```css
body{
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
.contenedor{
    max-width: 100vw;
        
    margin: auto;
}
.carousel-item{
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 300px;
    background: no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/056b8157f9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Viajes Chile</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="contenedor">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Viajes Chile</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" >
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quienes somos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Destacados</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" >
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494500764479-0c8f2919a3d8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8bGFuZHNjYXBlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494500764479-0c8f2919a3d8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8bGFuZHNjYXBlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494500764479-0c8f2919a3d8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8bGFuZHNjYXBlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501785888041-af3ef285b470?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8bGFuZHNjYXBlfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    
    

    <!-- Optional  JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

El código antes expuesto tiene la intención de presentar unas imágenes en un carrusel de bootstrap, solamente que , es deseable que las imagenes delcarrusel se superpongan a la barra de navegación, cuyas letras deben llevar el color blanco.
Obviamente las imagenmes son otras , son unas que tengo en mi computador, de todas maneras el efecto buscado debiera de conseguirse. En consecuencia, busco algún código css o bien en el propio bootstrap , que logre esto. Lo que ya aparece está bien. Además , el logo de la izquierda y los botones de la derecha debieran estar más centrados, aunque separados.Agradeceré una ayuda al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré este codigo que soluciona los problemas planteados

```
 <div class="container ">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent fixed-top " >
      <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#">Viajes Chile</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
          <li class="nav-item active ">
            <a class="nav-link  text-white" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only ">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Quienes somos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" >Destacados</a>
          </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled text-white" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    
    </nav>
 
  </div>

    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="Assets/img/carousel1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="Assets/img/carousel2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="Assets/img/carousel3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Fundamentalmente los cambios son :
Envolver la etiqueta nav por un div con clase container .
Luego aquí 
agregué la clase fixed-top
Finalmente , en estas etiquetas Quienes somos agregué la clase text-white y además en el archivo css personal, utilicé la clase navbar y le asigné la regla z-index:2